# Lazy registration - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, registration, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to rails and i'm trying to do lazy registration found here http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1679-lazy-user-registration-for-rails-apps/
And i have some errors:

- uninitialized constant AnonymousUser::ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS
  It's in my anonymous_user model
- after adding

  RetrospectionApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
  resources :posts, path: '/'
  root to: 'posts#index'
  end

  I see error

  uninitialized constant RetrospectionApp

I don't understand this route section and model. Can someone explain a bit and show solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are getting:

```
uninitialized constant RetrospectionApp
```

Because your app is not called that way. When creating your routes, you need to write the name of your app instead of **RetrospectionApp**

And I believe you are getting this:

```
uninitialized constant AnonymousUser::ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS
```

Because **ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS** is not defined. You need to tell your class what that constant is, for example by doing:

```
ACCESSIBLE_ATTRS = [:name, :email]
```

Which would say that the attributes :name and :email are accessible via mass assignment.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now i got (i guess) last one error:

undefined method `find_or_initialize_by_token' for #<Class:0x3e91168>

How this method should looks like?

Comment: That is a method defined by Devise. If your User model is inheriting from Devise you should be able to access that method from any User instance.